# What should be done when simpl does not reduce all the necessary steps?

Tags: coq

The following example is from chapter Poly of the Software Foundations book.

```
Definition fold_length {X : Type} (l : list X) : nat :=
  fold (fun _ n => S n) l 0.

Theorem fold_length_correct : forall X (l : list X),
  fold_length l = length l.
Proof.
intros.
induction l.
- simpl. reflexivity.
- simpl.
```

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
l : list X
IHl : fold_length l = length l
______________________________________(1/1)
fold_length (x :: l) = S (length l)
```

I expected it to simplify a step here on the left side. It certainly should be able to.

```
Theorem fold_length_correct : forall X (l : list X),
  fold_length l = length l.
Proof.
intros.
induction l.
- simpl. reflexivity.
- simpl. rewrite <- IHl. simpl.
```

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
l : list X
IHl : fold_length l = length l
______________________________________(1/1)
fold_length (x :: l) = S (fold_length l)
```

During the running of the tests I had an issue where `simpl` would refuse to dive in, but `reflexivity` did the trick, so I tried the same thing here and the proof succeeded.

Note that one would not expect reflexivity to pass given the state of the goal, but it does. In this example it worked, but it did force me to do the rewrite in the opposite direction of what I intended originally.

Is it possible to have more control over `simpl` so that it does the desired reductions?

Comment: What's the definition of `fold` (or what library are you using)?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying it. The `fold` is defined in the Poly chapter that I've mentioned and is the same as the one in your answer (under renaming.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I'll assume the definition of `fold` is something along the lines of

```
Fixpoint fold {A B: Type} (f: A -> B -> B) (u: list A) (b: B): B :=
match u with
| [] => b
| x :: v => f x (fold f v b)
end.
```

(basically `fold_right` from the standard library). If your definition is substantially different, the tactics I recommend might not work.

---

The issue here is the behavior of `simpl` with constants that have to be unfolded before they can be simplified. From [the documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.simpl):

> Notice that only transparent constants whose name can be reused in the recursive calls are possibly unfolded by simpl. For instance a constant defined by plus' := plus is possibly unfolded and reused in the recursive calls, but a constant such as succ := plus (S O) is never unfolded.

This is a bit hard to understand, so let's use an example.

```
Definition add_5 (n: nat) := n + 5.

Goal forall n: nat, add_5 (S n) = S (add_5 n).
Proof.
  intro n.
  simpl.
  unfold add_5; simpl.
  exact eq_refl.
Qed.
```

You'll see that the first call to `simpl` didn't do anything, even though `add_5 (S n)` could be simplified to `S (n + 5)`. However, if I `unfold add_5` first, it works perfectly. I think the issue is that `plus_5` is not directly a `Fixpoint`. While `plus_5 (S n)` is equivalent to `S (plus_5 n)`, that isn't actually the definition of it. So Coq doesn't recognize that its "name can be reused in the recursive calls". `Nat.add` (that is, "+") is defined directly as a recursive `Fixpoint`, so `simpl` does simplify it.

The behavior of `simpl` can be changed a little bit (see the documentation again). As Anton mentions in the comments, you can use the `Arguments` vernacular command to change when `simpl` tries to simplify. `Arguments fold_length _ _ /.` tells Coq that `fold_length` should be unfolded if at least two arguments are provided (the slash separates between the required arguments on the left and the unnecessary arguments on the right).[sup]1[\sup]

A simpler tactic to use if you don't want to deal with that is `cbn` which works here by default and works better in general. Quoting from [the documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.cbn):

> The cbn tactic is claimed to be a more principled, faster and more predictable replacement for simpl.

Neither `simpl` with `Arguments` and a slash nor `cbn` reduce the goal to quite what you want in your case, since it'll unfold `fold_length` but not refold it. You could recognize that the call to `fold` is just `fold_length l` and refold it with `fold (fold_length l)`.

Another possibility in your case is to use the `change` tactic. It seemed like you knew already that `fold_length (a :: l)` was supposed to simplify to `S (fold_length l)`. If that's the case, you could use `change (fold_length (a :: l)) with (S (fold_length l)).` and Coq will try to convert one into the other (using only the basic conversion rules, not equalities like `rewrite` does).

After you've gotten the goal to `S (fold_length l) = S (length l)` using either of the above tactics, you can use `rewrite -> IHl.` like you wanted to.

---

1. I thought the slashes only made `simpl` unfold things *less*, which is why I didn't mention it before. I'm not sure what the default actually is, since putting the slash anywhere seems to make `simpl` unfold `fold_length`.

Comment: `simpl` is not a very predictable tactic. A case like this is filed as issue [#7389](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7389). In this case a directive `Arguments fold_length _ _ /.` would help a bit.

Comment: Slash in an Arguments directive means "unfold iff the constant is applied to enough arguments" where "enough" is how many underscores/arguments come before the slash.  It can cause less unfolding for partially applied constants, though I've only ever seen it used to induce more unfolding.